# $\ln X$ derivative problem?

Tags: derivatives

$f(x) = x \ln(\cos3x - x^3)$, then $f'(x)$ = ?

I got

$$\begin{align}
&X * \left(\frac{1}{\cos3x - x^3}\right) * \left({-3}({\sin3x -3x^2})\right)\\ 
&= \frac{-(3x \sin3x) - 3x^3}{(\cos3x) -x^3}\\
\end{align}$$

and I don't know what to to next.
The correct answer on my homework should be : $\ln(\cos3x) - (3x\tan3x) -3x^2$

But I have no idea how to arrive it. Please help.

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: if f=ab, then f'=ab' +ba'  . You are missing the ba' part altogether

Comment: I hope the $\LaTeX$ I edited resembles what was intended.

Comment: Thank for all the editing helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** The first answer below is to the problem as originally stated. The remark has to do with what the actual problem probably is.

Your function is a **product**, $x$ times a messy function. To differentiate, use the Product Rule.

**Remark:** On the assumption that the reported **answer** is correct, the function you are asked to differentiate is actually $x\ln(\cos 3x)-x^3$.

Use the Product Rule on $x\ln(\cos 3x)$.

Comment: Oh yeah ! I see it now. Thank you so much for pointing out. I got the answer now. Thank you !

Comment: You are welcome. Parentheses need careful handling.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x) = x \ln(\cos3x - x^3)$, then $$f'(x) =\ln(\cos3x - x^3)+x\frac{1}{\cos3x-x^3}(-3\sin3x-3x^2)$$
$$=\ln(\cos(3x) - x^3)-\frac{3x(\sin(3x)+x^2)}{\cos(3x)-x^3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that you first have to use the product rule:
$$\begin{align}
f'(x) &= \frac{d}{dx}[x]\ln(\cos(3x) - x^3) + x \frac{d}{dx}\ln(\cos(3x) - x^3)\\
 &= \ln(\cos(3x) - x^3) + x\frac{1}{\cos(3x) - x^3}(-3\sin(3x) - 3x^2).
\end{align}
$$